# How to use buttons in email and receive click response using C#?

Tags: c#, html, email

This picture is and email with html. I used C# to make emails to be sent on gmail. My deepest question is, how to put action here in buttons? Like if I click the Threat button, it will signify to my C# that the picture is a threat. I know it's about json stuffs, but I don't know how to implement it. Thanks guys

[image: picture]

Comment: You'll need some kind of backend web-application that can handle the different links (thread/friend) and relay that information to your c# application.

Comment: Can all the down-voters perhaps leave pointers/comments to a new user about how to make the question better?

Comment: @Fishcake Once enough close-votes are cast, the reason will be displayed here (my guess is "too broad"). The tooltip on the down-vote button reads *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"* which is also a legitimate reason. Further reading: [How to ask for help on StackOverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy method is to use html link 
`<a href="{your custom link with encoded parameters}"><Button here/></a>`

around the button, the links must be encoded and carry custom parameters as query string or url/path. Similar technique is used in "verify email id" mails.

And at the backed the received parameters are decoded and analysed to take necessary action.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. can you suggest me some tutorials?

Comment: Are you using ASP webforms or ASp MVC?

Comment: This is a tutorial for Activation mail in ASP Webforms. Modify it according to your need
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-user-Confirmation-email-after-Registration-with-Activation-Link-in-ASPNet.aspx